# jQuery .click function not working only for first link

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have simple foreach loop in my razor view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.materijali) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink(item.sifra_materijala,   
                                "DetaljiMaterijala", 
                                "NormativiMaterijala", 

                                new { materijal = item.sifra_materijala.ToString() },
                                new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET" },
                                new { id = "mylink" })
        </td>
</tr>
```

And a jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#mylink').click(function () {
            $.post(this.href, function (json) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                $("#sifra_materijala").val(json.sifra_materijala.val())
                alert(json.sifra_materijala);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This calls controller action and returns some result that I need to show on my partial view.

When I click on any `href` link generated by `foreach` loop, controller action is regularly called and executed, except on the first one, when nothing happens...

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: What do you mean "any link", ID's are unique, you should only have one anchor with that ID `

Comment: @adneo all hrefs are <a id="myid" href = "/controller/action?parameter=somevalue"... so all generated links are ok, but every single href, href call action and send proper value to it, except first one.

Comment: @onedevteam.com Are you saying all your links have the same ID? If so, that's not valid HTML - IDs should be unique. Once an element has an ID of `myid`, no other element in the DOM should have that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done any dot net programming, let alone used razor views, but as I understand it, [`@Ajax.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink.aspx) generates an `<a>` element *and the JavaScript that makes the ajax call when the link is clicked*.

You have added a second ajax call, but for the first `<a>` element only. It applies only to the first one because even though you may have several `<a>` elements with `id="mylink"`, `id` values are supposed to be unique. The handler you supply also has an error in it: It references `data.responseText`, but `data` is undefined.

Instead of adding your own click handler, supply an [`OnSuccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onsuccess.aspx) callback function for the [`ajaxOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.aspx) parameter for the `@Ajax.ActionLink` call. And get rid of the `new { id = "mylink" }` parameter.